# What are the contents of /var/lib/rpm; where are they documented?

Tags: centos, rpm

In my `/var/lib/rpm`, I have the following files,

```
$ file *
Basenames:    Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Conflictname: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
__db.001:     Applesoft BASIC program data
__db.002:     386 pure executable
__db.003:     386 pure executable not stripped
Dirnames:     Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Group:        Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Installtid:   Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Name:         Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Obsoletename: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Packages:     Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
Providename:  Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Requirename:  Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Sha1header:   Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Sigmd5:       Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
Triggername:  Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
```

I can see that most of these files are Berkeley DB's. But, I can't find documentation on them.

- Where are they documented?
- What do these databases do?
- Does RedHat/CentOS provide any utilities to go exploring them with?

I'm building tools that integrate tightly with RPMs and these seem highly relevant to my task.

Answer (score 5):

This is low-level private data storage of the `rpm` tool and its `librpm` library. Your tools should probably use [the librpm API](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.14.0/) instead of trying to bypass the library, if at all possible.

That way, you will have a chance to maintain compatibility even if the developers of `librpm` and/or the `rpm` tool decide to extend things or change the data storage format.